# CACHING IN DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework

## I am using low level caching API

***I want to cache the queryset result in the django rest API, the problems i am facing is:***

1. Queryset result is dependent on input provided to the API.

```
 {
  "status": "Deactive",
   "location" : ["India","us"],
   "hashtagID": "1"
}
```

2. Suppose , I cache this result using some key, say ***Status_1***

```
cache_key = "Status_1"
query_set = ***query to filter the model using the above input***
cache.set(cache_key, query_set)
```

3. Now, if again user gives the same input to the API, ***How would i come to know that query_set respected to that input is already cached??***

### Simply, i want to create such a caching system in Django rest framework, where we can cache queryset which vary according to input provided to rest API.

Comment: Use input as your cache key.

Comment: suppose, if input to api is  {
  "status": "Deactive",
   "location" : ["India","us"],
   "hashtagID": "1"
}, then is it practical to use such a large object as cache key.?

Comment: @Abhinavverma- You want to cache the queryset based on your input. So, let's say your input is x then you can simply cache it as cache.set(x, qs).....

Comment: @Abhinavverma- Also remember you will need to keep a track of the DB such that if the queryset has changed in the DB such as if an insert, update, or delete happened.

Comment: @Abhinavverma- Additionally, this is an in-memory caching. So, keep in mind if your queryset is huge then caching it might have implications.

Comment: isn't there any way for django to take care of consistency between cache and database.????

Comment: @Abhinavverma you can write signals in Django to clear the cache whenever there is a change in DB.

Comment: But, if we are treating input as cache key, how can we delete that particular entry in cache through signal??